# Editing missing characters in some charmap/keyboard

Tags: x11, keyboard, tty

I use the *abnt2* layout on my american keyboard, but the backslash key <kbd>\</kbd> is missing.

How can I remap some glyph to an unused key or combination (eg. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> or <kbd>AltGr</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>)? I knows only that `/usr/share/X11/kbd/geometry/pc` contains the *abnt2* definition.

As <kbd>\</kbd> is a very important key, will X11 modifications be reflected on TTY terminals, so I can type it when X11 is down?